# Combining data from multiple tables to display in the MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I have two separate models in my MVC project

```
[Table("Table1")]   
 public class Companies : IEnumerable
 {      
     [Key]
    public double ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    public string Rank{ get; set; }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.ID;
        yield return this.Key;
        yield return this.Name;
        yield return this.Company;
        yield return this.Industry;
        yield return this.Rank;

    }
 }
```

and

```
[Table("Table2")]
 public class Registration : IEnumerable
 {
    [Key]
    public System.Guid Key { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue{ get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }


    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return this.Key;
        yield return this.FieldValue;
        yield return this.StartDate;
        yield return this.EndDate;

     }
  }
```

I need to display a combination of data in my view:

```
SELECT t2.FieldValue, t1.Name, t1.Company, t1.Industry, t1.Rank 
FROM Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Key=t2.Key
```

I created the following Context class:

```
public class TablesContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Companies> companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Registration> registration { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can pass the data for companies from the controller to the view using the following code:

```
private TablesContext tc = new TablesContext();
 var comps = (from c in tc.companies                                 
                    join r in tc.registry
                    on c.Key equals r.Key
      select new { FieldValue=r.FieldValue, Name=c.Name, Company=c.Company,Industry=c.Industry, Rank=c.Rank});
 return View(comps);
```

Now I am a bit stuck trying to make TablesContext class enumerable and loop through the result set in the View. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you'd normally (probably) go in ASP.NET MVC is you create a ViewModel something like this:

```
public class CompanyRegViewModel{
  public string FieldValue {get;set;};
  public string Name {get;set;};
  public string Company {get;set;};
  public string Industry {get;set;};
  public string Rank {get;set;};
}
```

Then instead of creating an anonymous object you can create an instance of the `CompanyRegViewModel` class  like this:

```
var comps= ..... select new CompanyRegViewModel{ FieldValue=r.FieldValue, Name=c.Name....};
```

On the other side you want to create a View whose model is a list of `CompanyRegViewModel`. (Doesn't have to be List<> though. It can be anything that implements IEnumerable<>). Here's an example part of your possible View:

```
......
<table>
foreach(var item in Model){
  <tr>
    <td>item.Name</td>
    <td>item.Company</td>
    <td>item.Industry</td>
    @*and so on*@
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a VIEW MODEL, i.e. another class that contains the fields that you need from both the tables. Then load it up with the data, make it into a LIST and pass that to the View. Then you can use a foreach to loop through it quite easily.

It is nicely explained here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10020862/3777098

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view model - see example below:
Plus try to use using statement to dispose the context after you are done using it.

```
public class CompanyRegistrationModel
{
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }

    public CompanyRegistrationModel Get()
    {
        using (TablesContext tc = new TablesContext())
        {

        var comps = (from c in tc.companies
            join r in tc.registry
                on c.Key equals r.Key
            select
                new CompanyRegistrationModel
                {
                    FieldValue = r.FieldValue,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Company = c.Company,
                    Industry = c.Industry,
                    Rank = c.Rank
                }).ToList();
        return comps;
        }
    }
}
```