# CQRS - What layer do QueryHandlers belong to?

Tags: design-patterns, cqrs

The answer to the question [In CQRS, should my read side return DTOs or ViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752483/636578) suggests that there should be one ReadModel (or projection, I am assuming these are the same) per widget.

But if this is the case, then does that not move the QueryHandlers into the presentation layer, so that there would be one QueryHandler per widget (in my case components in Angular)?

More specifically: Are QueryHandlers supposed to have functions like `getReadModelForProjectPageSidebarById(< projectId >)` or are they supposed to have functions like `getProjectById(< projectId >)`? If the latter is true, wouldn't that mean that an additional layer would be needed to map the ReadModel to a ViewModel that the widget/component could use?

Comment: My question is probably thightly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466065/viewmodel-location-when-doing-cqrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that this idea is clear: there can be more than one "read model" per "write model".

Logically, what's happening is not all that different from the "non CQRS" case; we are taking the information recorded by the write model, transforming it into an interesting representation, and returning it to the client (in your example, to the widget).

But this doesn't necessarily have to be done "live"; we can respond to the query by returning a cached copy of the representation.

If you consider, for instance, resources on the web -- HTTP has built into it a deep understanding of caching.  When an HTTP request is answered from the cache, it's basically a purely presentation handling of the query, no?

Thus, if you are handling the query by returning a representation from a cache, then the handler is going to be pretty shallow.

You are still going to need code somewhere that takes the *write* model's "book of truth" representation and converts it to the representation that is suitable for the cache.  But the execution of that code doesn't have to be synchronous with the *query* -- there are freshness vs latency trades that you can make.

> So let me see if I understand this correctly, the read model belongs to the presentation, but the query handler belongs to the application layer? Would you say that the following makes sense?
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyCSF.jpg

That's.... That's not bad at all.

> Or more importantly, neither of the query handler functions in my question are correct. The correct function call would we something along the lines of handle(< query of type QueryForReadModelABC >). So it's actually a request for a read model, and not a request for a specific resource/entity such as Project or User?

Yes.

Comment: Oh my, very interesting answer! So let me see if I understand this correctly, the read model belongs to the presentation, but the query handler belongs to the application layer? Would you say that the following makes sense? https://imgur.com/9ndFL3h

Comment: Or more importantly, neither of the query handler functions in my question are correct. The correct function call would we something along the lines of `handle(< query of type QueryForReadModelABC >)`. So it's actually a request for a read model, and not a request for a specific resource/entity such as `Project` or `User`?

Comment: Mind = blown. I knew there was something I was missing somewhere, just couldn't put my finger on it. Thank you!